# How to Install Semantic Wiki Extension on Mediawiki Running in Azure Web Site

Tags: php, git, azure, mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I have a currently running MediaWiki instance running in Azure Web Sites. I would like to install Semantic MediaWiki - so I basically need Composer (not sure why I'd need GIT installed). I've seen

http://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Installation/Windows_environment
http://sabbour.me/part-1-creating-a-composer-enabled-php-website-on-windows-azure-with-git-deployment/
http://sabbour.me/part-2-creating-a-composer-enabled-php-website-on-windows-azure-with-git-deployment/

The last 2 links pre-suppose that you first created your PHP site locally in a GIT repo and then push to a GIT-enabled Azure Web Site.  The MediaWiki site I'd like to install Semantic MediaWiki for is already up and running, and there isn't a straightforward way to just log into a machine and install Composer on there, as it's a PaaS (vs. IaaS).  Is there any easier way to go about this and can the relevant steps/procedures be provided? This seems like it would be a common use-case.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Semantic_Bundle

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Semantic Bundle](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Semantic_Bundle).

(Copying the question accepted by the asker in comments.)